# Does the original list decrease in size when I convert a list to a queue and poll?

Tags: java, arraylist, queue, pass-by-reference, memory-address

Assume I have an array list like

```
List<Integer> list = [1,2,3,4]; // ignore the syntax here
```

Then I convert the collection to a queue

```
Queue<Integer> queue = new LinkedList(list);
```

Then I do

```
queue.poll(); // remove element from queue
```

Does the original list also reduce in size For the mere fact both queue and list reference the same collection of Integers?

I was expecting that after `queue.poll()`, then `list.size()` will be less in size as well but that's not the case. Does it mean the queue and list are different datasets in memory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They may point to the same elements but they're different containers. The `Queue` is not backed by that list. References to the elements are copied from the list to the queue, but if you remove something from the queue it shouldn't (and doesn't) reflect on the list.

In particular the constructor for `LinkedList` looks like this

```
public LinkedList(Collection<? extends E> c) {
    this();
    addAll(c);
}
```

The `addAll` method, in turn, look like this (after calling a version of itself and providing the size):

```
public boolean addAll(int index, Collection<? extends E> c) {
    // omitted for brevity

    Object[] a = c.toArray();

    // omitted for brevity

    for (Object o : a) {
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked") E e = (E) o;
        Node<E> newNode = new Node<>(pred, e, null);
        if (pred == null)
            first = newNode;
        else
            pred.next = newNode;
        pred = newNode;
    }

    // omitted for brevity
}
```

(where `first` is the first node of the linked list)

So, as you can see, it creates its own nodes. So yeah, if you remove any of those nodes you're not removing anything from the original list.

Answer (score 0):

`Queue<Integer> queue = new LinkedList<>(list);` (please don't use raw types) creates a **copy** of the original collection. So no. Removing an element from `queue` will not *modify* `list`. They are indeed reference to different regions in memory. It's the same operation as

```
Queue<Integer> queue = new LinkedList<>();
queue.addAll(list);
```

Also, I know you said ignore it, but

```
List<Integer> list = [1,2,3,4];
```

should be

```
List<Integer> list = List.of(1, 2, 3, 4);
```